# Multithreading in Unity Stuttering When Generating 3D Terrain (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, terrain

I'm very new to the concept of multithreading, so I'm still learning and have no idea if what I'm doing could be considered heresy or not. I'm developing a game right now in my free time for fun in Unity, mainly as a way for me to learn more about 3d environments, and in it, I'm adding terrain generation. I tried to add multithreading but I don't think I did it correctly or in an efficient way as my game stutters a lot when loading chunks.

Here's how the multithreading looks in my terrain generation class:

```
public class TerrainGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    // Other global variables
    public GameObject angularWPPref;
    private List<AngularWP> renderList;
    private List<AngularWP> awps;
    private bool threadRunning = false;
    private Thread myThread;

    void Start() {
        renderList = new List<AngularWP>();
        awps = new List<AngularWP>();

        for (int x = 0; x < wpAmount.x; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < wpAmount.y; z++) {
                GameObject worldPiece = Instantiate(angularWPPref); // Create the game object for the chunk/worldPiece

                worldPiece.GetComponent<AngularWP>().setPosition(new Vector3(x * worldPieceSize.x * voxelScalar, 0, z * worldPieceSize.z * voxelScalar));
                // Set the position of the worldPiece

                awps.Add(worldPiece.GetComponent<AngularWP>());
                // Add the Angular World Piece class object from the game object to a list so the chunk data can be added to it in the other thread.
               
            }
        }
    }

    void Update() {

        if (awps.Count > 0 && !threadRunning) {
            ThreadStart newThread = delegate {
                generateVoxels(awps[0].position, awps[0]);
            };
            myThread = new Thread(newThread);
            myThread.Start();
            threadRunning = true;
        }
        // Start a new thread if there are more chunks to be loaded and myThread isn't running

        if (renderList.Count > 0) {
            renderList[0].setup(); // Initialize the mesh and add the material 
            renderList[0].refreshMesh(); // Clear the mesh
            renderList[0].finalize(); // Add all vertices and tris to the mesh, recalculate normals, and add the mesh to the game object
            renderList[0].initialPhysicsSetup(); // Set up the physics of the mesh
            renderList[0].setPosition(new Vector3(renderList[0].position.x, 0, renderList[0].position.z)); // Set position again (because for some reason it was getting set in random places on the y-axis)
            renderList.RemoveAt(0); // Remove the current world piece from the render list

        }
    }

    public void generateVoxels(Vector3 position, AngularWP awp) {
        awps.RemoveAt(0); // Remove the current world piece from the list
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    
        // Terrain Generation Code

        awp.renderMesh(); // Create the mesh
        renderList.Add(awp); // Add the world piece to the render list
        threadRunning = false; // Tell the program that this thread is done running
    }
}
```

Is there anything really noticeable that I've done wrong that I'm not seeing? The code works properly and generates the terrain correctly, so there aren't any errors, it's just that it stutters.

The only thing that I could see causing problems is the fact that I'm only using 1 additional thread to load the terrain as opposed to multiple, so maybe it's still slowing down because of that? That doesn't make a lot of sense based on my understanding of how multithreading works, but maybe I'm wrong.

Another point where it could be an issue is starting the thread or finishing rendering the current chunks when using the data in the main thread. I could see this causing problems, but I'm not sure how I would improve it.

I've taken a look at Unity's job system, but I couldn't figure out how to convert my code to work with it and felt like trying to learn how to multithread could be more beneficial since I could use the skills in other non-Unity projects in the future. Is this something that I should return to and give it another shot or can I achieve the same thing with multithreading?

I'm really lost when it comes to this stuff, so any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no specific Unity skill, but you seem to have concurrent access to awps and renderList. Are these containers thread-safe? Some debug printout of the current time in milliseconds inside the Update loop could maybe give you a hint why frame rate is uneven.

Comment: Thank you! I checked Microsoft's documentation and apparently List<> isn't threadsafe, so I'll definitely have to do some experimentation. I'll respond again with updates about the time printouts, maybe that'll give me my solution.

Comment: I've taken a look at my code and it looks like the actual render loop of my function was causing my lag, not the multithreading. What's confusing is that I run this code at runtime whenever I've attempted to add terrain modification, so it doesn't really make much sense as to why it would cause so many problems now. I've trimmed down what the rendering does but it's still quite laggy. Maybe there are some problems with the multithreading that I overlooked? I'm still very confused about how this all works and what I should do. Also using thread-safe containers like ConcurrentQueue did not work.

Comment: If you add enough debug printouts you will figure it out.  From my own experience doing multithreaded graphics (opengl), your approach with starting a new thread on each Update seems wrong, and having a Thread.Sleep(1); seems wrong as well. Instead you should maybe have a thread running continuously at full speed generating the terrain, and the other thread rendering the results. You can synchronize the threads using barriers if needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier?view=net-5.0

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I noticed a large improvement by adding a pause break between new threads of .75 seconds after the previous one started, but maybe I should try out running a continuous thread. I'm assuming it'll have to end at some point as I'll run out of data for it to go through, but I'll try to write a new terrain generation function that will take in all of the chunks instead of individual ones and iterate through those. Thanks!